# How can I configure my Phonegap App to scale its viewport accordingly with the phone's resolution?

Tags: android, cordova, scale, autoresize

I'm developing an Android App using Phonegap. It's a "question and answer" game and it has a complex layout comparing to the majority of mobile apps.

How do I configure to automatic rescale in different resolutions?

Until now I'm doing the same process I do to create simple web pages: slicing images and placing into HTML with CSS.  But I noticed the planned resolution to work on is about 540x960, bigger than a lot of phones I'm used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I archived that simply using css transform scale in body.
Something like this:

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Works, but I found I also had to add some code to adjust the positioning of elements on the page to keep everything correct across multiple form factors/screen resolutions.  In particular, I noticed that content had a tendency to fly off the top of the page at higher screen resolutions.

Comment: Hi thanks for still answering your own question. I assume you use some js to determine screen size and dynamically arrive at the scale factor.. right? or any other simpler way?

Comment: @Matical, no, I didn't need in this app, was just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think in my case this line in the index.html does it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Hope it helps :).

What concerns images you have wo work with different resolutions and media querys I guess!

Comment: I already use that meta-tag, what I asked for was something like a total re-scale of my page. Like Flash does with an app.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369661/2163837) might be the answer bit relevant.

> How to make device width-height based html & css via PhoneGap